# Data only updating to database after program -restart

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

firstly thanks for all the help on these forums, I have found it extremely helpfull! Unfortunately I have a problem that I can't quite figure out. I have written a program in vb.net which uses a LogIn screen which opens up a HomePage where you can create messages for other people to see.

I can create new messages but they do not show in my datagridview unless I close the program and re-open it. Then they are present.

```
Public Class frmMessage
Dim newMsgRow As Prototype1DataSet.MessagesRow
Dim editMsgRow As Prototype1DataSet.MessagesRow


Private Sub MessagesBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Me.Validate()
    Me.MessagesBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.Prototype1DataSet)
End Sub

Private Sub MessageForm_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the Prototype1DataSet.Messages table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.'
    Me.MessagesTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Prototype1DataSet.Messages)

End Sub


Private Sub btn_SaveMsg_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_SaveMsg.Click
    'Check if inputs are valid and then saves new message and returns to Home Page'
    If CheckDataInputs() Then
        If frmHomePage.editMsgFlag = False Then
            SaveNewMessage()
        ElseIf frmHomePage.editMsgFlag = True Then
            EditMessage()
        End If

        MessageBox.Show("Message saved", Me.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK)
        Me.Hide()
        frmHomePage.Show()

    End If
End Sub


Private Function CheckDataInputs() As Boolean
    'Check if any inputs are left empty'
    Dim InputsCheck As Boolean = True
    If txt_MsgFrom.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please state whom the message is from", Me.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK)
        Me.txt_MsgFrom.Focus()
        InputsCheck = False
    ElseIf txt_MsgTo.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter message recipient", Me.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK)
        Me.txt_MsgTo.Focus()
        InputsCheck = False
    ElseIf txt_Message.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a message", Me.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK)
        Me.txt_Message.Focus()
        InputsCheck = False
    ElseIf txt_MsgStatus.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please select message status", Me.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK)
        Me.txt_Message.Focus()
        InputsCheck = False
    End If
    Return InputsCheck
End Function


Private Sub SaveNewMessage()
    'Saves new message into Messages table'
    newMsgRow = Prototype1DataSet.Messages.NewMessagesRow()

    newMsgRow.From = txt_MsgFrom.Text
    newMsgRow._To = txt_MsgTo.Text
    newMsgRow.Message = txt_Message.Text
    newMsgRow.Status = txt_MsgStatus.Text
    newMsgRow._Date = date_Msg.Text

    Prototype1DataSet.Messages.AddMessagesRow(newMsgRow)

    MessagesTableAdapter.Update(Prototype1DataSet)
    Prototype1DataSet.Messages.AcceptChanges()
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Thanks matzone, I added the DGV.DS = Dataset.Table right after the AcceptChanges() and it works, but now it is creating a double input in my DGV. When I create another message then the previous double is removed but the new entry has a double...

Answer (score 0):

It's usually happened in DataGridView Databound table ..

If you already update the table or make some changes in the table then you must do

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = MyTable
```

So the table will be reloaded in your DGV ..